# How not to ignore the spaces that precede constructor arguments?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a constructor for a sparse array that would take N arguments. If there are spaces before the argument, then this shifts its index by one position. At least I imagine it so

I see this for the first time and I have no idea how to release it. This is a task, so I cannot change the input data for the constructor.

```
SparseArray<float,  3 > array0(1.0f, 2.0f);
SparseArray<double, 10> array1(      4.0,    7.0);
```

Arrays after initialization should be like these
`array0[0] == 1.0f`,`array0[1] == 2.0f`. 
And `array1[1] == 4.0`, `array1[3] == 7.0` It turns out as if spaces occupied positions `0` and `2` in `array1`.

Comment: Spaces are mostly ignored by the C++ parser. You cannot change the language syntax unless you write your own preprocessor that edits the source code before the compiler sees it.

Comment: Also 1) this is extremely confusing. Nobody who reads the code will grasp this behavior. Most code formatters will delete these spaces. 2) why do you shift by one? What if you want to skip 5 items?

Comment: Spaces are ignored by the C++ *lexical analyser,* except insofar as they help to delimit tokens. One space has exactly the same meaning as a million of them. There is absolutely nothing you can do about that.

Comment: thanks for the answers.

Comment: Other ways to solve these kind of things include using a sentinel "value" (an object you pass) that means "empty element here". Or a variant or that where you pass object with information about position (which can then easily be arbitrary large) and value to add at that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you 're trying to do is impossible since you don't have any control on the C++ parser and honestly makes no sense for anyone who will use your code.

Unless you write some kind of preprocessor (just don't), best option here is just to add zeros wherever is necessary:

```
SparseArray<double, 10> array1( 0, 4.0, 0, 7.0);
```

If you still want to use whitespaces, an alternative is to use string as argument and then parse it yourself, extracting numbers and finding whitespaces:

```
SparseArray<double, 10> array1("   4.0,   7.0");
```

I would go with the first option.